# New Xamarin.Forms CollectionView doesn't allow multi pre-selection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView in my Xamarin.Forms project:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" x:Name="CategoryColView"
                SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" 
                SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference CategoryColView}, Path=SelectedItems}"
                SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategoryItems}">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout ...>
            <BoxView .../>
               <StackLayout ...>
                  <Label .../>
                     <Image .../>
               </StackLayout>
            <BoxView/>
         </StackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I included the entire XAML element, but the only important part is the `SelectedItems` property. It is bound to the following viewmodel implementation:

```
class ViewModel {

    private ObservableCollection<object> selectedCategories { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedCategories {
        get => selectedCategories;
        set {
            selectedCategories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    //...

    ctor() {
        //...
        var alreadySelectedCategoryItems = alreadySelectedCategories.Select(pc => new CategoryItem { PlantCategory = pc, IsSelected = true }).Cast<object>();
        SelectedCategoryItems = new ObservableCollection<object>(alreadySelectedCategoryItems);
        //...
    }
}
```

The rest of the implementation should be irrelevant. My aim is to have pre-selected values.

**First:** I noticed that if the `T` in `ObservableCollection<T>` is not `object`, everything is ignored. Just like in Microsoft's example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-pre-selection). If the `T` is e.g. of type `CategoryItem`, literally nothing happens, as if the `ObserveableCollection` were completely ignored.

**Second:** `alreadySelectedCategoryItem` contains 2 elements in debugger mode, but then the last line in the constructor throws a:

> **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException**
>
> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index

Of course, since this is Xamarin.Forms and VS for Mac, the error is thrown on the Main function, not at its actual location...

Am I doing something wrong, or is CollectionView just still buggy?

Comment: Hmm not sure about your first assumption, that T should be Object. Take a look at a test app I did with CollectionView, I was able to just use ObservableCollection with a regular class. https://github.com/Depechie/CollectionViewChallenge/blob/master/CollectionViewChallenge/CollectionViewChallenge/Views/KudosView.xaml#L7 and https://github.com/Depechie/CollectionViewChallenge/blob/master/CollectionViewChallenge/CollectionViewChallenge/Views/CollectionViewChallengePage.xaml.cs#L36

Comment: Second assumption is going to be a real Xamarin bug, I could reproduce it in the example app that I linked above. I will file a report.

Comment: @Depechie Thanks for the first clarification! It must be something in my code then.

Comment: Yeah if the second one is indeed a general bug, github issue would be best place to log it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was creating new `CategoryItem` instances as the pre-selected ones, which is invalid, as they weren't by default the same instances that were in the `CollectionView.ItemsSource` property. I should have filtered the ItemsSource instances and put them as the pre-selected ones. Like this:

```
var alreadySelectedCategoryItems = alreadySelectedCategories.Select(pc => new CategoryItem { PlantCategory = pc, IsSelected = true }).Cast<object>();
SelectedCategoryItems = Categories
    .Where(sci => 
         alreadySelectedCategoryItems.Any(alreadySelected => 
              alreadySelected.PlantCategory.Id == sci.PlantCategory.Id);
```

So the items are selected off the ItemsSource itself and not created as new.

*Although the error message was not as desired, so [Xamarin.Forms team is going to fix that](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6963).*

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedItems` is read-only,you could not use like `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategoryItems}"` in xaml
[image]

you could try to  change in your behind code like:

```
CategoryColView.SelectedItems.Add(your selectItem 1);
CategoryColView.SelectedItems.Add(your selectItem 2);
CategoryColView.SelectedItems.Add(your selectItem 3);
```

Comment: It is not `readonly` - https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selecteditems?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_SelectableItemsView_SelectedItems

Comment: @iSpain17 do you see it only have get method ?

Comment: @iSpain17 you could check the image i updated above

Comment: Being `readonly` and only having a `get` method isn't the same. And still, in XAML you are using the BindableProperty of SelectedItems... https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selecteditemsproperty?view=xamarin-forms Even the documentation says what I am doing is valid.